# Find the biggest difference between indexes

Tags: java, arrays, array-difference

Hey Stackoverflow Community,
I got a little problem where I´m stuck at the moment..
I have to write a code, that have to find the biggest " temperature " difference between given days.
These are my Arrays:

```
int[] day = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30};
int[] temperature = {12,14,9,12,15,16,15,15,11,8,13,13,15,12,12,11,7,13,14,11,9,11,10,7,11,6,11,15,10,7};
```

I need to have an Output like:
The biggest temperature difference was between Day X and Day X with the difference of X Degrees
Can someone give me a hint whats the best way to do it?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: A good way to do it in one pass is to keep track of a minimum and maximum, and use those somehow.

More in depth (Don't read if you want to figure it out yourself):

- Create a minimum and maximum value to store the index of the min and
  max, respectively (can be initialized to 0 and 0)
- Loop through each element of the temperatures array
- For each element, if it is less than the element at min, change min to the current index
- If it is greater than the element at max, change max to the current index
- Once you finish, you will have indexes in which the difference is greatest, simply add one to get the day.

Here's some java code:

```
void greatestDifference(int[] day, int[] temperature) {
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < temperature.length; i++) {
        if (temperature[i] < temperature[min]) {
            min = i;
        } else if (temperature[i] > temperature[max]) {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    int difference = temperature[max] - temperature[min];
    System.out.println("The biggest temperature difference was between Day " + (min+1) + " and Day " + (max+1) + ", with the difference of " + difference + " Degrees.");
}
```

Hope this helped!

Edit: If you plan on having values in `day[]` that aren't just 1, 2, 3, etc., you can replace the `i+1`s in the print statement to `day[min]` and `day[max]` to get the specific days at which it held those min and max values.

Also, as @SirRaffleBuffle pointed out, the index in the for loop can start at one, since the values at zero would only compare to themselves, but this is not necessary.

Edit 2:
The problem seems to actually have been to find the greatest difference between consecutive days. No worries! Here's some code for that:

```
import java.lang.Math;

void greatestDifference(int[] day, int[] temperature) {
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < temperature.length-1; i++) {
        if (abs(temperature[i] - temperature[i+1]) > abs(temperature[max] - temperature[max+1])) {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    int difference = temperature[max+1] - temperature[max];
    System.out.println("The biggest temperature difference was between Day " + (max+1) + " and Day " + (max+2) + ", with the difference of " + difference + " Degrees.");
}
```

This just loops through each value in `temperatures` and finds the difference between it and the temperature the next day. If the difference is greater than the current max, we update the max. P.S. `Math.abs()` finds the absolute value.

Comment: @ScaryWombat The max and min variables are storing indexes, not values.

Comment: Yep, just noticed

Comment: Hey :)
Thanks for your answer, I will try it out later and I thank you in advance.
If I have more questions about it or understanding problems of the code, I will answer again.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Marius1773 Of course! Feel free to ask any questions you have. And if it works for you, don't forget to accept the answer. (It'll give both of us some reputation lol)

Comment: Nice answer. One tiny quibble, index `i` can be started at 1 rather than 0.

Comment: @SirRaffleBuffle True. Almost did this, but I figured the asker is probably newer to this, so I didn't want to cause any confusion. Good point though!

Comment: I tried it right now, and Its working in my Code right now, but I think I messed it up a little bit, because I need to find the biggest change from day 1 to day 2 for example, like he checks how big the temperature difference/change between day 1 and day 2 is and checks if there is any bigger change in the Array, I think I didnt wrote it good enough, sorry. But very good explanation

Comment: @Marius1773 Sorry to hear that! I'll try to help. Is it about the biggest change between 2 consecutive days? If so, this an even easier problem. I'll update my post with some code for you to try.

Comment: Yes, it is about to find the biggest change between 2 consecutive days in the whole Array and name the Days like 15 and 16 and the value of the change. :)

Comment: @Marius1773 Just updated my post. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hmm Strange, it says cannot find symbol  `int difference = temperature[i+1] - temperature[i];` 
Im doing anything wrong I guess ^^

Comment: @Marius1773 My bad! Replace the `i`s in that line with `max`. I updated the code in my answer as well.

Comment: @SpencerLutz yea, if I werent blind at 5am I would have seen this on my own ^^
Is there any possibility that the Difference is not showing as "-5" ?
Thanks !

Comment: @Marius1773 Sure! Do you want it to always show the greatest increase, or the greatest absolute value of the difference?

Comment: I want it to have the increase value like if Day 1 has 13 and Day 2 has 17 it should show "4" :)

Comment: @Marius1773 For example, if day 1 is 13, day 2 is 17, and day 3 is 10, what would you want the output to be?

Comment: In this Example the output should be: " The biggest temperature difference was between Day 2 and Day 3 with the difference of 7 Degrees

Comment: @Marius1773 Sure! The easy way to do this is to replace `int difference = temperature[max+1] - temperature[max];` with `int difference = Math.abs(temperature[max+1] - temperature[max]);`. This takes the absolute value of that difference and removes the negative.

Comment: Hell Yea! Thank you very much, Im sorry for this spongy question ^^
For my next Questions I will be more precise!